# Mysql query create table does not works by php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to copy 2 tables structures into a new database. 
I use a function that makes by herself the SQL command: When i execute the code on phpmyadmin the code gets executed but when I execute this by PHP, it doesn't execute.

How is possible?

The sql command is this:

```
CREATE TABLE `tabella_1` ( 
  `campo1` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `campo2` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,  
  `campo_3` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`campo1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
CREATE TABLE `tabella_2` (  
  `campo1` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  `campo2` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,  
  `campo_3` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`campo1`)  
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

Thanks

Comment: What happens in PHP? What driver are you using? Can you show PHP usage?

Comment: Did you tried to run queries 1 by 1, maybe that can cause issue on mysql driver ?

Comment: That's the code..
$sql2 is the query that I wrote before
$connessione = mysql_connect("","root","");
    mysql_select_db("alternanza_".$anno); 
    if (mysql_query($sql2, $connessione)) {
     echo "Il database alternanza_".$anno." è stato aggiornato!";
     echo("</br><a href='test2.php'>indietro</a>");
    } 
    else {
     echo("Errore nell'aggiornamento del database alternanza_".$anno."- ".mysql_error());
     echo("</br><a href='test2.php'>indietro</a>");
     }
    mysql_close($connessione);

Comment: wheres your PHP code?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'execute this by PHP'. If there is PHP code please post it. Also, try running one query at a time.

Comment: Per the PHP manual `mysql_query` (which shouldn't being used anyway) won't execute multiple querys; `multiple queries are not supported`. -http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: You have 2+ statements in the same "line".  the mysql driver for PHP does not allow multiple statements in a single `query()` call. it's a cheap defense mechanism against one form of [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: I need to make 2 tables structure copy of a db in another db... i made a function that creates the sql (I'm shure that the generated sql works, i tried to put it in "SQL" form in php my admin and it works) but if I execute it in PHP using mysql_query() it doesn't works, it says that i've got an error in the sql command

Comment: Understood... so how can i made it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update this code with your database connection details:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `tabella_1` ( `campo1` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `campo2` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, `campo_3` int(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`campo1`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table 1 created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

// sql to create table
$sql2 = "CREATE TABLE `tabella_2` ( `campo1` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `campo2` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, `campo_3` int(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`campo1`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci";

if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table 2 created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks henry TK... but there's still a problem... the sql is generated by a "SHOW CREATE TABLE" command... so it makes 2 queries in output... how can I get the sql code to create the tables structure copy 1 by 1?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

I putted in a array() the functions and it works!

Tkanks to everybody!